# \fltitem does not work properly when I compile large document

Tags: floats, lists

I've used the `\fltitem` to avoid the list problems recently. The `\fltitem` works very well when I compile a small document, however, the `\fltitem` does not work properly when I compile a large document that contains several sub-document by using `\include` and many pictures. Sometimes, the pictures can not be shown or overlap the words in the pdf document. Could you show me where the problem is?

Here is an example that the second item can not work properly and I guess it is the same reason that cause the large document not work.

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{floatflt}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \fltitem{\lipsum[1]
\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{floatingfigure}

\lipsum[1]}

\fltitem{\lipsum[1]

\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{floatingfigure}

\lipsum[1]
}
    \end{enumerate}
    
   \end{document}
```

Here is the result in which the right half is blank in the second item.[image]

Comment: Sorry, but you will need to provide an example that show the problem you get. We cannot do much with an example that works (after one replaces the image as we do not have it)

Comment: I've edited the question and the problem shown in the question is some similiar with the ones in the large document. And in this one tikz is used so that it can be compiled independently.